# Inline CSS set by jQuery 'resize event' gets reset to default once window is done resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have a backbone view called HeaderView and I'm trying to update each header's children's padding on resize. The padding only gets updated while I'm resizing, then when I stop resizing the css is set back to it's default as if I did `$('element').css('padding-left', '');`

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.$headers = this.$el.find('.myHeaders');
    this.resize();

    $(window).on('resize.header', _.bind(this.resize, this));
  },
  resize: function() {
    this.$headers.each(function() {
      var l;

      if ($(this).index() <= 2 ) {
        l = $(this).offset().left;
        $(this).find('#child').css('padding-left', l);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a backbone view that's part of a larger site that's built on the Demandware platform. Demandware comes with a responsive.js file that was overriding my changes and setting the css back to its default state. Commenting out the file from loading fixed my issue.